# My App not showing text colors except black and white on nexus 4 lollipop device

Tags: android, textview, themes, nexus-4

My App is not showing text colors except black and white on nexus 4 lollipop device. My app contains just a text view with hello world red colored text. But it is appearing black on my device.

Emulator is showing Red colored "Hello world!" but my device shows it in black color.... No matter whatever color i choose my nexus 4 lollipop device shows it in black color.... Sorry i am new here so i can not post images yet.

This is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#f00"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Consider posting some code to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Same app is showing colors on emulator but not showing on my device.

Comment: paste your code lines and if possible provide screenshot of device and emulator both to compare. Thanks

Comment: This is my xml code..

Comment: Please don't use the Answer section to add the xml code. Use the [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29470202/edit) button and add the code to your question.

Comment: Do you find any solution of your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
android:textColor="#ffff0000"
```

instead of

```
android:textColor="#f00"
```

Comment: not working...  same black color is appearing on my physical device...but emulator is showing accurate color.